# How do I statistically compare two maps?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, xy, correlation

I need to statistically compare two maps in order to determine if the spatial distribution of the data is correlated or not.

I have two files in ArcGIS

1. XY location of foreign-owned firms
2. XY location of domestically-owned firms

I want to test if there is a correlation between the location of foreign and domestic firms.

I am comparing points within the same map and within the same period (I have 7 time periods, a dynamic analysis would be nice, but too complicated for now)

How might I go about this in ArcGIS?

From my own research, I can see that there is no universal way to do this.

Some suggestions I have seen online are Mantel tests and Cross-covariance analysis

Or, Using the Geoda or Crimestat softwares (I have tried both, but I am still at a dead-end).

I just want to calculate what the correlation between the two maps is, I know there is many ways to do it, but I can't find the correct tools to do even just one of them.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Thanks! I have updated it, hopefully it is satisfactory.

Comment: This is a problem in statistical point pattern analysis. It requires some careful thought about what precise hypothesis you are trying to test. Just asking if "there is correlation between locations A and locations B" isn't well defined. One possibility is to test the hypothesis that both points are realisations from the same underlying, unobserved, intensity. To do this kind of thing really needs R and some of the spatial stats packages therein...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will check out r, I am having no luck in ArcGIS.